# Windows CTF/war games/reverse engineering/exploit challenges

Tags: windows, exploit, reverse-engineering

War Games are fun but mainly deal with Linux reverse engineering.

Example: http://blackbox.smashthestack.org:85/

Does anyone know of similar online games for Windows security?

Comment: The links on that page link to compromised/defaced pages; while it's a CTF there is no guarantee that someone didn't put a real malicious link in there.

Comment: a lil xss never hurt anyone

Comment: You never know... sure, it can't do much long-term damage but I'd rather not get redirected to some nasty NSFW website while being at work.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has annual "Build the shield" contest annually.  https://buildtheshield.microsoft.com.
This might interest you

Comment: Is this still going on? Seems a bit dated with no recent info.

Comment: @the_endian seems like they didn't have one after 2016